# mySQL Select priority - select one row OR another (select a default or "fallback" row)

Tags: php, mysql

This should be fairly simple but it's tricky to find the right term to use when searching.

In the query below, I need to select `WHERE lang='en'` ONLY if `WHERE lang='nl_NL'` returns nothing. In other words, I want to find all records `WHERE script='generic'`, prioritised by `lang=nl_NL`

```
SELECT * FROM international WHERE script='generic' AND (lang = 'nl_NL' OR lang = 'en')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM international WHERE script = 'generic' AND lang = CASE
  WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM   international
    WHERE  script = 'generic'
       AND lang   = 'nl_NL'
    LIMIT  1
  ) THEN 'nl_NL'
  ELSE 'en'
END
```

Comment: Seems to work great, Thanks! Is it a bit slow?  `Query Time 0.114s`

Comment: @cronoklee: Do you have an index on `(script,lang)`?

Comment: I didnt, but I do now and it works better: `Query Time 0.024s`. Thanks a lot @eggyal

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of one way you could get the specified resultset:

```
SELECT i.*
  FROM international i
 WHERE i.lang = 'nl_NL'
    OR (i.lang = 'en' 
        AND NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 FROM international d WHERE d.lang = 'nl_NL')
       )
```

It's not clear from your question when you want the "`script='generic'`" predicate applied.

```
SELECT i.*
  FROM international i
 WHERE ( i.script = 'generic' AND i.lang = 'nl_NL')
    OR ( i.script = 'generic' AND i.lang = 'en'
         AND NOT EXISTS 
           ( SELECT 1
               FROM international d
              WHERE d.lang = 'nl_NL'
                AND d.script='generic'
           )
       )
```